# input date (year) into website calendar using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking to loop through a few years on a pet insurance website. I am having issues with this website in particular, as I have already perform similar functions on other websites. The code (which includes the website) are below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

path = r"C:\Users\d-DAN\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path)

driver.get("https://www.offerte.smartpaws.de/")

    for year in range(21,6,-1):

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="id_form-0-dob"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_form-0-dob_root"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/select[1]'))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    element = '//*[@id="id_form-0-dob_root"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/select[1]/option['+str(year)+']'
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element))).click()
```

So, in the above, I connect to the website using selenium, then I run a loop going backawards (based on website structure for options), click on the option to open the calendar, click on the dropdown for year, and try to select each option.

I have tried using `send_key` with the date as well, with a loop on range of the years to send each date as an input, but did not work. Saying it is not accessible for send key.

The result I was looking for was being able to input the last 10 years (i.e. 01.01.2022, 01.01.2021, etc)

Thank you in advance.

For more question please post them bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is more you want you want to add to your test but I managed to recreate and fix it in a way that allows you to loop through each of the dates specified in your range.

Firstly, you need to add 2000 to each value in the range or it will interpret the range value literally. E.g:

```
ele = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ''.join(('//select[@class="picker__select--year" and @aria-controls="id_form-0-dob_table"]//option[text()=',str(2000+year),']')))))
```

Secondly, you need to move the calendar opening to outside the for loop because you currently have no way of closing and reopening the calendar input (ignore this if you actually plan to add a way of closing and reopening the calendar to your loop).

Thirdly (optional), your time.sleep commands are not doing anything as ExpectedConditions does the waiting for you. So you can remove these.

[Here](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/d3743904-1b2a-49f7-931b-3c54e938ca98?projectId=bugtestproject2) is an example test case I made with these fixes. I broke apart the click command so you can see in the logs that it goes through each year value. If you want to edit, its free to make an account (doable by clicking "edit").